# Add character at the beginning of line with specific string in line - Python

Tags: python, text, replace

I have a file with few thousand lines like this:

```
0.5  AA
2.7 AA
45.2 AA
567.1 CC
667.5 AA 
4456 AA
1005.2 CC
```

I want add comment signs "//" at the beginning of each line contains string "CC".

I have code like this:

```
import fileinput

file_name = input("file path: ")

for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name, inplace=1):
    if 'CC' in line:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.replace(line,'// '+line)
    print (line)
```

Everything works fine but the file looks like that after execute the code:

```
0.5  AA

2.7 AA
    
45.2 AA
    
// 567.1 CC
667.5 AA
    
4456 AA
    
// 1005.2 CC
```

Why after execute the code i have the new line spaces after line without changes? How I can remove this?
Second question is: How i can save this file as a new file?

Summarizing:
I need to write code which in a txt file will add "//" to the beginning of each line containing "CC" and save it as a new file.

Comment: Each line ends with `\n`. You need to `rstrip()` every line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution works well, what you think about it ?

```
filepath = input("original file :")
filepath2 = input("result file : ")

with open(filepath, "r") as f, open(filepath2, "w") as f2:
    for line in f:
        f2.write(line if not 'CC' in line else "//" + line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a character issue in your input file. Maybe `.strip()` instead of `.rstrip()` will work better. `.rstrip()` only removes whitespaces at the right of the string while `.strip()` removes them left and right. Something like this should work:

```
inputFile = open('data.txt', 'r')
outputFile = open('outputFile.txt', 'w')

for line in inputFile:

    outputLine = line.strip() + '\n'
    if 'CC' in line:
        outputLine = '//' +  outputLine
    outputFile.write(outputLine)
 
inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra new lines is due to the '\n' characters present already in lines of the file, you can prevent that by changing to

```
print(line, end='')
```

I dont know why you prefer file input module for reading files, becuase I find the default method open to be quite satisfactory as you can read and write textfiles, binaryfiles, etc... As for your question:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution :

```
p="name_of_original_file.txt"
file=open(p,"r")
s=file.read()
file.close() 

new_s=""
for line in s.splitlines():
    if 'CC' not in line:
        new_s+=line+"\n"
    if 'CC' in line:
        new_s+='// '+line+"\n"
    print (line)

p="name_of_new_file.txt"
file=open(p,"w")
file.write(new_s)
file.close()
```